# Issues when installing Windows on a new computer

Tags: windows-7

I have recently bought a new PC. It has rather good specifications with an Nvidia Gefore 1060 3gb card, 8 GB RAM, 1 TB HDD. This is all fine, however there is an issue whenever I wish to instal a Windows 7 OS. I have tried several different types of Windows 7 installing them from a memory stick booted in the BIOS system. Every time it loads the Windows sign, it freezes in the "language" bar. Any idea why is the PC doing this?

Comment: Specifically what PC did you buy? What processor? etc...full specs please.